# Minimum Preserving Transformations

Tags: reference-request, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, global-optimization

If $f:X\rightarrow Y$, $g:Y\rightarrow Y$ are functions and $g$ is monotone increasing function then
$$
\operatorname{argmin}_{x \in X} f(x) 
=
\operatorname{argmin}_{x \in X} g\circ f(x) .
$$
X and Y are partially ordered sets.

So monotonicity is sufficient for preserving extrema.  Are necessary and sufficient conditions known for $g$ to preserve minima?  If so does anyone know a good reference?

Comment: I think you mean $f: X \to Y$  and $g: Y \to Z$, where $Y$ and $Z$ are partially ordered sets: otherwise $\text{argmin}$ has no meaning.

Comment: Monotonicity is not sufficient, If $g$ is monotone decreasing then the minima is not preserved. Consider $X = [0, 1], f(x) = x, g(x) = 1-x$

Comment: Actually I think you want it totally ordered.  In a partially ordered set, there are two possible meanings of argmin (you may require $f(x)$ to be a **minimal** element of $f(X)$ or a **least** element of $f(X)$), and neither of those is preserved by (strictly) monotone increasing functions $g$.  The problem is that you could have $g(f(a)) < g(f(b))$ where $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are incomparable.